# Pythonic way of splitting loop over list in two parts with one iterator

Tags: python, list, iterator

I am processing a text file with an irregular structure that consists of a header and of data in different sections. What I aim to do is walk through a list and jump to the next section once a certain character is encountered. I made a simple example below. What is the elegant way of dealing with this problem?

```
lines = ['a','b','c','$', 1, 2, 3]

for line in lines:
    if line == '$':
        print("FOUND END OF HEADER")
        break
    else:
        print("Reading letters")

# Here, I start again, but I would like to continue with the actual
# state of the iterator, in order to only read the remaining elements.
for line in lines:
    print("Reading numbers")
```

Comment: can't you just call `lines.index('$')` to get the separator position?

Comment: The use case is more complex than that, I am just searching for a general way of doing this.

Comment: it would be productive if you post your real problem rather than this trivial one then

Comment: The real problem has first a header, seperator and then an set of arbitrary sections with case specific number of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually can have one iterator for both loops by creating your line iterator outside the for loop with the builtin function `iter`. This way it will be partially exhausted in the first loop and reusable in the next loop.

```
lines = ['a','b','c','$', 1, 2, 3]

iter_lines = iter(lines) # This creates and iterator on lines

for line in iter_lines :
    if line == '$':
        print("FOUND END OF HEADER")
        break
    else:
        print("Reading letters")

for line in iter_lines:
    print("Reading numbers")
```

The above prints this result.

```
Reading letters
Reading letters
Reading letters
FOUND END OF HEADER
Reading numbers
Reading numbers
Reading numbers
```

Comment: This is the most python answer. +1

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could use `enumerate` to keep track of where you are in the iteration:

```
lines = ['a','b','c','$', 1, 2, 3]

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line == '$':
        print("FOUND END OF HEADER")
        break
    else:
        print("Reading letters")

print(lines[i+1:]) #prints [1,2,3]
```

But, unless you actually need to process the header portion, the idea of @EdChum to simply use `index` is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way and maybe more pythonic:

```
lines = ['a','b','c','$', 1, 2, 3]
print([i for i in lines[lines.index('$')+1:]])
# [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to read each element after `$` to different variables, try this:

```
lines = ['a','b','c','$', 1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = [i for i in lines[lines.index('$')+1:]]
print(a, b, c)
# 1 2 3
```

Or if you are unaware of how many elements follow `$`, you could do something like this:

```
lines = ['a','b','c','$', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a, *b = [i for i in lines[lines.index('$')+1:]]
print(a, *b)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more that one kind of separators, the most generic solution would be to built a mini-state machine to parse your data:

```
def state0(line):
  pass # processing function for state0

def state1(line):
  pass # processing function for state1

# and so on...

states = (state0, state1, ...)     # tuple grouping all processing functions
separators = {'$':1, '#':2, ...}   # linking separators and states
state = 0                          # initial state

for line in text:
  if line in separators:
    print('Found separator', line)
    state = separators[line]       # change state
  else:
    states[state](line)            # process line with associated function
```

This solution is able to correctly process arbitrary number of separators in arbitrary order with arbitrary number of repetitions. The only constraint is that a given separator is always followed by the same kind of data, that can be process by its associated function.